# Cross-Origin Request Blocked:(Reason: CORS request failed) in backbone.js app deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, heroku

I have built a Backbone.js based app and deployed it to heroku at link(https://prototypeapp.herokuapp.com) but I face a strange issue:
when I request the app in the browser,the part of code that is related to backbone.js doesn't work and the web console of my firefoxe browser display the following error: " Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8080/timeline. (Reason: CORS request failed)." despite that the app was working well locally.
I have read about this problem but nothing help me to solve it. could anyone help me to know the reason of this problem and how to fix it ??
my server.js code is as follows:

```
/**
* A simple API hosted under localhost:8080
*/
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var Twit = require('twit')

var client = null;


function connectToTwitter(){
 client = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         '*******'
, consumer_secret:      '*******'
, access_token:         '*******'
, access_token_secret:  '*******'
});
}
 //get the app to connect to twitter.
 connectToTwitter();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));

 /** 
   * Get the account settings for the user with the id provided.
  **/
 app.get('/profile/:id', function(request, response){

 response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 

 client.get('users/show', {screen_name:request.params.id}, 
 function (err, reply) {

  if(err){
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    response.send(404);

  }
  if(reply){
   // console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    response.json(reply);
  }

  });
});


 /**
 * Runs a search given a query  
 **/
 app.get('/search/:query', function (request, response) {

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
//search term is 
var searchTerm = request.params.query;

client.get('search/tweets', { q: searchTerm, count: 20 },
function(err, reply) {

  if(err){
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    response.send(404);

  }
  if(reply){
   // console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    response.json(reply);
  }

  });

});

/**
 * Returns the twitter timeline for the current user 
 **/
 app.get('/timeline', function (request, response) {

  response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
 client.get('statuses/home_timeline', { count:6 },
 function (err, reply) {

  if(err){
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    response.send(404);

  }
  if(reply){
 //   console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    response.json(reply);
  }

 });

});

 var allowCrossDomain = function(req, response, next) {
 response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
 response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
 'OPTIONS, GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
 response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,
 Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    response.send(200);
  }
  else {
   next();
 }
 };

 app.configure(function() {
 app.use(allowCrossDomain);
//Parses the JSON object given in the body request
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));

 });

//Start server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

my timeline collection is as follows:

```
 define(['backbone', 'app/model/Tweet'], function(Backbone, Tweet) {

var com = com || {};
com.apress = com.apress || {};
com.apress.collection = com.apress.collection || {};

 com.apress.collection.Timeline = Backbone.Collection.extend({

//the model that this collection uses
model: Tweet, 
//the server side url to connect to for the collection
url: 'https://localhost:8080/timeline',

initialize: function(options){
    //anything to be defined on construction goes here
},



});

return com.apress.collection.Timeline; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` means, essentially, 'my own computer.' You're running a web server on the Internet - not your computer - so connecting to `url: 'https://localhost:8080/timeline'` doesn't make sense. It's better to use a relative url like `/timeline`.

Comment: oh,yeah that is right. Sorry for the lack of my attention.thank u so much @hunterloftis